# Bing Maps - Directions Manager: Uncaught ReferenceError: sj_evt is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bing-maps

## Problem

Basically, I noticed an error in the console when our site is loaded in stating that `Uncaught ReferenceError: sj_evt is not defined`. I had made no changes prior that would have caused this error to display.

Here is the error in full:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sj_evt is not defined
at t._subscribeToTaskFocusEvent (www.bing.com/rms/InternalControlsPluginBundle/cj,nj/7cecd1c6/0f79a01b.js?bu=rms+answers+Maps+AnonymousBegin*InternalControls.en*InternalControlsPluginStart*TaskBarTemplate*TaskBarViewModel*TaskBar*TaskBarItem*CategorySearchTemplate*UserTipTemplate*UserTipControl*CategoryDropdownControl*CategoryDropdownManager*CategoryItem*PrintDialog*PrintLogHelper*PrintDialogViewModel*PrintManager*SharingDialog*SharingDialogViewModel*SharePanelTemplate*SharePanel*BirdsEyeV2DialogViewModel*BirdsEyeV2Dialog*CommutabilityControl*CommutabilityControlOverlay*CommutabilityLogHelper*CommutabilityControlTemplate*ContextualTaskbarManager*InternalControlsPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1)
at t.initialize (www.bing.com/rms/InternalControlsPluginBundle/cj,nj/7cecd1c6/0f79a01b.js?bu=rms+answers+Maps+AnonymousBegin*InternalControls.en*InternalControlsPluginStart*TaskBarTemplate*TaskBarViewModel*TaskBar*TaskBarItem*CategorySearchTemplate*UserTipTemplate*UserTipControl*CategoryDropdownControl*CategoryDropdownManager*CategoryItem*PrintDialog*PrintLogHelper*PrintDialogViewModel*PrintManager*SharingDialog*SharingDialogViewModel*SharePanelTemplate*SharePanel*BirdsEyeV2DialogViewModel*BirdsEyeV2Dialog*CommutabilityControl*CommutabilityControlOverlay*CommutabilityLogHelper*CommutabilityControlTemplate*ContextualTaskbarManager*InternalControlsPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1)
at www.bing.com/rms/InternalControlsPluginBundle/cj,nj/7cecd1c6/0f79a01b.js?bu=rms+answers+Maps+AnonymousBegin*InternalControls.en*InternalControlsPluginStart*TaskBarTemplate*TaskBarViewModel*TaskBar*TaskBarItem*CategorySearchTemplate*UserTipTemplate*UserTipControl*CategoryDropdownControl*CategoryDropdownManager*CategoryItem*PrintDialog*PrintLogHelper*PrintDialogViewModel*PrintManager*SharingDialog*SharingDialogViewModel*SharePanelTemplate*SharePanel*BirdsEyeV2DialogViewModel*BirdsEyeV2Dialog*CommutabilityControl*CommutabilityControlOverlay*CommutabilityLogHelper*CommutabilityControlTemplate*ContextualTaskbarManager*InternalControlsPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1
at www.bing.com/rms/InternalControlsPluginBundle/cj,nj/7cecd1c6/0f79a01b.js?bu=rms+answers+Maps+AnonymousBegin*InternalControls.en*InternalControlsPluginStart*TaskBarTemplate*TaskBarViewModel*TaskBar*TaskBarItem*CategorySearchTemplate*UserTipTemplate*UserTipControl*CategoryDropdownControl*CategoryDropdownManager*CategoryItem*PrintDialog*PrintLogHelper*PrintDialogViewModel*PrintManager*SharingDialog*SharingDialogViewModel*SharePanelTemplate*SharePanel*BirdsEyeV2DialogViewModel*BirdsEyeV2Dialog*CommutabilityControl*CommutabilityControlOverlay*CommutabilityLogHelper*CommutabilityControlTemplate*ContextualTaskbarManager*InternalControlsPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1
```

From what I've found so far, this is related to loading the Directions Manager module in Bing Maps. The only thing it seems to affect is the way that the Directions Manager re-renders itself after calling `.clearAll()`. It creates a sort of red flashing on each of the tiles that it reloads.

I have been able to reproduce the error on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox as well as the red flashing on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and occasionally on Internet Explorer.

I saw [a post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3364448a-57c2-4fb8-9028-eb2068bbdfd3/script-error-when-loading-map?forum=bingmapsajax) regarding this error in the MDSN support forums that mentioned possible timing issues with the loading of the module. However, from how I have the map and Directions Manager loading, this shouldn't be an issue. The post was then closed stating the error resolved itself, but it doesn't seem to be resolved for all users.

---

## Code

Here is how I'm calling Bing Maps in my index file:

```
<script src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=initialize' async defer></script>
```

Note that this error occurs on both the release and experimental branches of V8.

Here is the function that the callback refers to:

```
function initialize () {
    const CENTER = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.96375272262944, -93.2353971897461);

    // Initialize the map
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        credentials: API_KEY,
        minZoom: zoom,
        center: CENTER,
        disableStreetside: true,
        disableStreetsideAutoCoverage: true,
        enableClickableLogo: false,
        showLocateMeButton: false,
        showMapTypeSelector: false,
        disablePanning: disablePanning,
        disableZooming: disableZoom,
        draggable: isDraggable
    });

    // Creates all busses and adds them to an array
    bus1 = {
        directionsManager: null,
    };
    bus2 = {
        directionsManager: null,
    };
    bus3 = {
        directionsManager: null,
    };
    buses = [bus1, bus2, bus3];

    // Add the traffic layer
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Traffic', function () {
        trafficLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficManager(map);
    });

    // Add the directions manager
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
        bus1.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
        bus2.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
        bus3.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus1.directionsManager, 'directionsError', function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.message + "\r\nResponse Code: " + e.responseCode);
        });
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus1.directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function(e) {
            directionsUpdated(e, bus1);
        });

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus2.directionsManager, 'directionsError', function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.message + "\r\nResponse Code: " + e.responseCode);
        });
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus2.directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function(e) {
            directionsUpdated(e, bus2);
        });

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus3.directionsManager, 'directionsError', function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.message + "\r\nResponse Code: " + e.responseCode);
        });
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus3.directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function(e) {
            directionsUpdated(e, bus3);
        });

        // Call for the current version of our bus data
        requestServerUpdate();
    });

    console.log("Initialization complete.");
}
```

I cut out most of the unneeded code and left in everything related to the modules and map loading. If it seems like something crucial is missing or you would like more code, please let me know and I'd be happy to update the post.

---

## Question

**So I guess the main question is, is there anything that can be done to resolve the `Uncaught ReferenceError: sj_evt is not defined` error I'm occurring or get rid of the red flashing that it is causing?**

Thanks to everyone in advance for any advice!

---

## Edit

[Here](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/zRNpZd) is a Codepen displaying the `Uncaught ReferenceError: sj_evt is not defined` error specified. The flashing error is not displayed though as the .clearAll() function is not implemented in the example.

To supplement that, here is an example of what it looks like:
[image: Red Flashing Example]

Upon further testing, I found that the red is caused by the inclusion of colored Polygons nearby. With those removed, it's just large blurred sections of the map that appear.

Comment: Using the code you provided I'm unable to reproduce that error.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again rbrundritt! Also, I've added a Codepen that should correctly display the error (you'll just have to replace the API key with a temporary one as I'd rather not throw mine out online) as well as an image of the red flashing/blurring that occurs.

Comment: Whelp, I once again went back to my code and tried the release branch and that seemed to resolve the error. So either the Bing Maps team rolled the release branch back or I completely messed up implementing the release branch when doing my testing for this post. Probably the latter of the two.

Comment: The Bing Maps team hasn't touched the release branch since last month. There is an update happening in a couple weeks.

Comment: Odd, could be a browser issue or a myriad of other issues. I'll update the post further in the future if I find any more information or just resolve it if it never shows up again.